# toroidal knot patch/ribbon

Tags: parametric

I know I can create a toroidal knot ribbon: If **B** is the binormal to the curve, adding *u***B** to the parametrization for some *u* between -1 and 1 should do it. You get a surface described by **r**(*t*,*u*). However, this ribbon will always be tangent to the surface of the torus and not "hug" it.

How can I create the equations that describe a toroidal knot patch that wraps on the surface of the torus? (I envision this as the portion of the torus surface between two knots that are exactly the same, only offset from each other by some amount).

Comment: Sorry, but why was this down-voted? Is there something I can do to better state my question?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to achieve this? All advice is welcome.